# how to read many points through point class in java?

Tags: java

```
public class point3d {
float x;
float y;
float z;  
public point3d(float x, float y, float z){
   this.x = x;
   this.y = y;
   this.z = z;
}
public point3d(){
    x = 0;
    y = 0;
    z = 0;
}
public float getX(){
    return x;
}
void setX(float x) {
    this.x =x;
}
public float getY(){
    return y;
}
void setY(float y) {
    this.y =y;
} 
public float getZ(){
    return z;
}         
void setZ(float z) {
    this.z = z;
}
public String toString()
{
    return "(" + x + ", " + y + "," + z + ")";
}        
}
```

This is a point3d class code i have written and I want to read multiple points through this point3d class, which are given in main class how could i achieve this. pls help me?

Comment: what do you mean by "read multiple points through this point3d class" ? Please share your `main class`.

Comment: by multiple points do you means x,y,z

Comment: Make an array of `point3d` in your `main`?

Comment: how to create an array of point3d in main? pls kindly help me?

Comment: `point3d[] arrayOfPoint3D = new point3d[];` Just like any other array. This is basic stuff, I recommend you do some java basics reading online.

Comment: when i tried to create an array an error occurred saying that illegal intializer of point3d.

Answer (score 3):

First of all, a class should start with an uppercase according to [Naming Conventions](http://java.about.com/od/javasyntax/a/nameconventions.htm).

Secondly, you should create a container inside your main class for your `Point3d`s, for example a `List`.

Next you can iterate over it and execute your logic.

```
List<Point3d> points = new ArrayList<>(); // this is JDK7
List<Point3d> points = new ArrayList<Point3d>(); // this is before JDK7, pick one

points.add(new Point(4F, 3F, 2F)); // let's create some points to iterate over
points.add(new Point(23F, 7F, 5F));

for(Point3d point : points) {
    // do some logic with point
}
```

A followup question would be, what are you trying to achieve with these `points`?

Comment: I wanted to call two points from this point3d class to rectangle class and wanted to create a rectangle and return those 4 rectangle points using this point3d class.

Comment: please any one help me with this?

Comment: How are you going to make a rectangle with 3 points?

Comment: `new ArrayList(); this is JDK7` is invalid and it should be should be `new ArrayList<>()`

Comment: @ajduke: Please ellaborate why this is invalid. I always declare my `ArrayList` this way without any issues. Maybe I can learn something here :)

Comment: @user2427209 We'll need more specific requirements to match your needs.

Comment: @Aquillo i can see you trying to use the Type Inference, but that requires the `<>` which is diamond operator to achieve it , please look at http://goo.gl/abQb7. and btw without use of diamond operator you will get warnings not the issues from compiler

Comment: @ajduke Thanks for pointing that out! Will change it accordingly ;)

Comment: I took point to as 3 coordinates, and i need two points which are base points and by adding the height to these two base points, I can construct rectangle. So, for this i need to pass 2 points from the point3d class to the rectangle class which i have written.

Answer (score 0):

I think I understand your question now. You want to make a 3 dimensional rectangle, which means you need 4 points (unless you want it to have depth too, in which case you need 8).

So all you need is an array of 4 of your `point3d` class:

```
point3d[] rectangle = new point3d[4];
```

Then you just need to assign to that array:

```
rectangle[0] = new point3d(x,y,z); //note that the first element is 0, not 1
rectangle[1] = new point3d(x2,y2,z2);
...
```

And when you want to access them later:

```
System.out.println(rectangle[0].getX());
```

I suggest you do some reading: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html